# Scroll view in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

How can i add scroll view in the xml file with having Relative layout, Recycler view, TextView, Image View. Below is the respective xml code :

Please go through the below code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StoryList">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/skandaimagestory"
    android:src="@drawable/pictureskanda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/skandaimagestory"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="17dp"
    android:text="SURVIVORS TALES"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/Heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:background="#f6facf"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/story_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need a ScrollView? Like what do you try to achieve? If the only reason you need it is to place some views above and and make it scroll together you just need to use CoordinatorLayout with AppbarLayout. Way more elegant

Comment: In case you are trying to achieve a list of elements with the first being an header I suggest you to keep only the RecyclerView and use different ViewTypes.

Anyway you shouldn't use "wrap_content" as height for ScrollView and RecyclerView.

Comment: Thank you for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView**

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `ScrollView` layout there must have only one root layout. Notice that I have used `LinearLayout` as root layout. It could be also `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".StoryList">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/skandaimagestory"
        android:src="@drawable/pictureskanda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/skandaimagestory"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="17dp"
        android:text="SURVIVORS TALES"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/Heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:background="#f6facf"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/story_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

         </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to have Linear Layout (vertical) in ScrollView

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StoryList">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/skandaimagestory"
    android:src="@drawable/pictureskanda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/skandaimagestory"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="17dp"
    android:text="SURVIVORS TALES"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/Heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:background="#f6facf"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/story_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NestedScrollView` instead of your regular `ScrollView` like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/skandaimagestory"
        android:src="@drawable/pictureskanda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/skandaimagestory"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="17dp"
        android:text="SURVIVORS TALES"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/Heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:background="#f6facf"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/story_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And then when initialising your `RecyclerView` just add these two lines:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```